# Getting byte value for numbers between 0 and 255?

Tags: java, file, byte

I need to get the byte / 8 bit representation for numbers between 0 and 255. Is there any comfortable way to do this in Java? Seems like most methods are intended to be work with 4 byte long integers? My final goal is to write several 8 bit values to a file.

Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 18):

To complete Alex's answer:

```
int i = 255;
byte b = (byte) i;
System.out.println("b = " + b); // b = -1
int i2 = b & 0xFF;
System.out.println("i2 = " + i2); // i2 = 255
```

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with byte.  It is **signed**, e.g. -128 to 127.  If you want 0-255, when you go to print it out, you always need to `&255` (as JB Nizet did in his example)

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with [`byte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) type? If you only store data and don't do arithmetic and don't need decimal representation for other reasons then it should not matter that it is signed.

Comment: Sorry for the necropost but, as one example Java's Color object requires numbers from 0-255. If you're working on something very complicated, and require a massive list of these numbers, it is much more efficient to store them as a list of bytes than a list of ints.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 byte = 8 bits = 00000000~11111111 (binary) = 0~255 (unsigned byte)
>   = 0x00~0xFF (hex decimal)

C#:

> 1 byte value is: 0~255

Java:

> 1 byte value is: -128~127

If you want get 0~255 (unsigned byte) value in java:

> byte b = **(byte)** value;

example: byte b = **(byte)** 200;

> int b = value **& 0xFF**;

example: int b = 200 **& 0xFF**;

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to read it into a `int`, just mask it with `& 0xff`. I suggest a layer of indirection between `(In|Out)putStream`. Cover details such as endianness.

In the write object:

```
public void unsignedByte(int value) throws IOException {
    if (!(0 <= v && v <= 0xff) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    out.write(v);
}
```

In the read object:

```
public int unsignedByte() throws IOException {
    int v = in.read();
    if (v == -1) {
        throw EndOfFileException();
    }
    assert 0 <= v && v < 0xff; 
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class play {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String path = "./src/play.cue"; // file content:\xff\xdd
        
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);

        int[] bytes = new int[(int)new File(path).length()];

        int b, i=0;
        while( (b=fis.read()) != -1){bytes[i] = b; i++;}

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));

    }
}
```

Output:
[255, 221]

Answer (score -2):

Java byte is signed from -128 to 127, if u want to get the representation from 0 to 255 i use this 2 functions

```
public static byte fromIntToByte(String value) throws Exception {
        return fromIntToByte(Integer.parseInt(value));
    }

    public static byte fromIntToByte(int value) throws Exception {
        String stringByte = "";
        if (value < 0 && value > 255) {
            throw new Exception("Must be from 0<=value<=255");
        }
        if (value <= 127) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                stringByte = String.valueOf(value % 2) + stringByte;
                value = value / 2;
            }
        } else {
            value = value / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                stringByte = String.valueOf(value % 2) + stringByte;
                value = value / 2;
            }
            stringByte = "-" + stringByte;
        }
        System.out.println(stringByte);
        byte b = Byte.parseByte(stringByte, 2);
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, nor is it even correct. Converting a byte to a series of bits and passing it through string functions will be very slow.